# How to implement a custom random process object?

Tags: programming, random

I want to implement a custom random process *thing*<sup>1</sup> to pass to `RandomFunction`.

The process I have in mind is conceptually extremely simple: two *alternating* Poisson processes, with rates *λ*<sub>1</sub> and *λ*<sub>2</sub> <sup>2</sup>.  I'm hoping that there's a comparably simple way to combine two `PoissonProcess` *things* to yield the *thing* I'm after.

Does anyone know how to do this?

---

<sup><sup>1</sup>The [documentation](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RandomFunction.html) for `RandomFunction` mumbles something to the effect that this function takes a "*proc*" as its first argument, but, as usual, leaves it to the user to guess what this could be.</sup>

<sup><sup>2</sup>Just to be clear, these two processes are "in series", not "in parallel".  IOW, only one of the two processes is active at any given time, and it remains active until its next event, at which point the other process becomes active.</sup>

Comment: _proc_ is the process

Comment: @chuy: I realize that; what I'm getting at is that "*proc*" is a completely opaque reference; the documentation conveys no information whatsoever about how one would implement such a *thing* programmatically in the Wolfram language.

Comment: [TransformedProcess?](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TransformedProcess.html)

Comment: It's akin to how `RandomVariate` takes a _dist_.  _dist_ is a distriubtion.

Comment: @chuy: Sorry, I don't think you understand my point, but I don't know how to explain it any better than I have.  I can only hope others can see what I mean.

Comment: It does seem as if you want something like `TransformedProcess[If[(* event *), p1[t], p2[t]], {p1 \[Distributed] PoissonProcess[λ1], p2 \[Distributed] PoissonProcess[λ2]}, t]`. But there's still a nice question here: "I have a process that is not built-in; how do I get `RandomFunction[]` to recognize and simulate it?"

Comment: @kjo I feel you. In my own words, I'd state an example of a question like "how do implement a process such as `myOwnPoissonProcess = ...` without actually using the built-in process functions?"

Comment: It's relatively easy to get the same output as the `RandomFunction`  of such a process would result in without using `RandomFunction`.

Answer (score 4):

`ContinuousMarkovProcess` provides a general mechanism for creating a Markovian (i.e. memoryless) random process with continuous index (e.g. time) and countably finite states. A Poisson process has countably infinite states, so you can't quite get there from here. You can specify [alot](http://hyperboleandahalf.blogspot.com/2010/04/alot-is-better-than-you-at-everything.html) of states to study the process before it hits some maximum.

Your two transition rate process, but counting only up to a maximum of `m=100`, would be:

```
m = 100;
\[Lambda][1] = 1/2;
\[Lambda][2] = 2;
q = SparseArray[{
    {i_?EvenQ, j_} /; i == j - 1 -> \[Lambda][1],
    {i_?OddQ, j_} /; i == j - 1 -> \[Lambda][2]}, {m, m}];
q = q - DiagonalMatrix[Total[q, {2}]];
p = ContinuousMarkovProcess[1, q];
```

And a plot to emphasize the rate change between states:

```
T = 10;
ListLinePlot[
    RandomFunction[p, {0, T}],
    InterpolationOrder -> 0,
    ColorFunctionScaling -> False,
    ColorFunction -> Function[{t, p}, If[EvenQ[Round[p]], Black, Red]]
]
```